# Micro:bit python Rock Paper Scissors debugging

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Micro:bit python. I am writing a code for a 'Rock, Paper,Scissors' game with a scoring system. However, it responds to shaking once then automatically shows a picture after even though no one has shook it. Could you suggest a way to fix this?

```
from microbit import *
import random

count = 0

paper = Image("99999:"
            "90009:"
            "90009:"
            "90009:"
            "99999")
rock = Image("00000:"
            "09990:"
            "09990:"
            "09990:"
            "00000:")
scissors = Image("00099:"
                "99090:"
                "00900:"
                "99090:"
                "00099:")
while True:
    while True:
        if accelerometer.is_gesture("shake"):
            display.clear()
            choice = random.randint(0, 2)
            if choice == 0:
                display.show(rock)
                break
            elif choice == 1:
                display.show(paper)
                break
            else:
                display.show(scissors)
                break
    while True:
        if button_a.is_pressed():
            count = count + 1
            display.scroll(str(count))
            break
        elif button_b.is_pressed():
            count = count - 1
            display.scroll(str(count))
            break
        elif pin0.is_touched():
            display.scroll(str(count))
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand from the documentation,
 try changing this line of code: 
`if accelerometer.is_gesture("shake"):` to `if accelerometer.was_gesture("shake"):`

Their difference, from the docs:
for is_gesture:

> Return True or False to indicate if the named gesture is currently active.

for was_gesture:

> Return True or False to indicate if the named gesture was active since the last call.